# I'm getting a non-zero id back from MySql's LAST_INSERT_ID when doing INSERT IGNORE

Tags: mysql

I have done several inserts with a connection, and my most recent insert is an INSERT IGNORE statement. After this, I call LAST_INSERT_ID(), expecting it to be zero if the INSERT IGNORE silently failed. However, what it does is return the last successfully inserted ID, even if that ID was inserted by a statement other than my most recent insert statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I got around this was to make sure that LAST_INSERT_ID was being reset on my connection after I retrieved it.

I did that by retrieving LAST_INSERT_ID this way:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), LAST_INSERT_ID(0);
```

So, I get the ID back, and then set it to zero. Any subsequent call to LAST_INSERT_ID will get a zero value, unless an insert actually succeeds.